# Allow tags and attributes in post and pages content

Tags: functions, theme-development, filters, allowedtags

I am trying to allow the "onclick" attribute on links as well as some html tags such as iframe to the content displayed in posts and pages.

In my theme's functions.php file, I tried

- removing filters such as wpautop

  ```
  function rm_wpautop($content) {
    global $post;
    // Get the keys and values of the custom fields:
    $rmwpautop = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpautop', true);
    // Remove the filter
    remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    if ('false' === $rmwpautop) {
    } else {
      add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    }
    return $content;
  }
  // Hook into the Plugin API

  add_filter('the_content', 'rm_wpautop', 9);
  ```
- adding tags

  ```
  add_action( 'init', 'allow_contenteditable' );
  function allow_contenteditable() {
    global $allowedposttags;

    $tags = array( 'iframe' );
    $new_attributes = array( 'contenteditable' => array() );

    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
      if ( isset( $allowedposttags[ $tag ] ) && is_array( $allowedposttags[ $tag ] ) )
          $allowedposttags[ $tag ] = array_merge( $allowedposttags[ $tag ], $new_attributes );
    }
  }
  ```

without any success.

Comment: I am away from my 3.8 sandbox right now but `iframe`s and `onclick` attributes are not stripped when tested on an old 3.6 install. Are you sure this is a Core problem and not a theme or plugin one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a privilege thing: Adding those tags as an admin works, while with other users having less privileges (editor, etc) does not.